# Display HTML extracted from XML file in a tableView

Tags: iphone, html, xml, sdk

So I have an XML file that looks a little like this

```
<xml>
    <post>
      <![CDATA[
        THis is the HTML inside of the CData
        <br>
        I want this to be parsed and displayed in a UITableView
      ]]>
    </post>
    <post>
      <![CDATA[
         <img src="http://foo.com/foo.jpg" />
      ]]>
   </post>
</xml>
```

I am able to extract the CDATA and assign it to an array. However, I need a simple way to parse it and display it in the UITableView.
Just basic stuff such as displaying images.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095782/using-nsxmlparser-with-cdata

Comment: :/ that topic seems to only cover the CDATA portion, which I am more then fine with. Its just the HTML parsing that is giving me a headache. Thanks for the speedy response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd use libxslt and convert to pure html and use the SeismicXML iPhone sample - http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1599127

There is a great deal of information about parsing the data correctly and string corrections of html data.  Though, again I'd use the built in libxslt.