# NSXMLParser and CDATA

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser, cdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using NSXMLParser with CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095782/using-nsxmlparser-with-cdata)

Im using `NSXMLParser` to parse xml data from my server.
when user send a text message  to another user my server is using CDATA tag to wrap the user text, because user text can break the xml structure.

My question is will the `NSXMLParser` know how to handle the CDATA automatically? Is it built in the NSXMLParser mechanism?

Comment: It's worth noting that, even with CDATA, user input can break the XML structure e.g. if you type in  `foo bar ]]>` << looks like the end of the CDATA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used `NSXMLParser`, but a quick lookup to the documentation of the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol reveals method `parser:foundCDATA:`.

Comment: Thanks @Monolo, I did not know I could do that. Is that a standard markdown feature? If so I guess I need to brush up my markdown (but do not spill this with Gruber).

Comment: TBH, I don't know - but the "local" version is documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/

Comment: Oh, thanks again. I had seen that page, but skimmed through only until the point where it linked to Gruber's site for more info. Turns out the non standard additions to markdown are documented past that, right at the end. I should facepalm+RTFM I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Its part of the XML spec so an XML parser has to support it.